# Почему значение переменной изменилось до вызова функции?

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Всем привет. Дано:

```
function outerFunc() {
  let counter = 0;
  return function innerFunc() {
    return counter++;
  }
}
const innerFunc = outerFunc();
console.dir(innerFunc); // 1-ый вывод
innerFunc();
innerFunc();
console.dir(innerFunc); // 2-ой вывод
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почему при первом выводе в консоль отображается, что переменная counter во внешнем лексическом окружении innerFunc уже со значением 2? Если ДО первого вывода в консоль я НЕ вызывал innerFunc и, как следствие, не повышал значение переменной? Со вторым выводом вопросов нет, всё, как надо, потому что я два раза вызвал innerFunc.

Comment: проблема не в функции а в консоли... она ленивая и отображает данные на момент открытия стрелочек в ней

Comment: где-то был дубль - не найду...... придёт гранди и закроет))

Comment: Добавлю к комментарию @Алексей Шиманский Потому что ссылка одна и та же

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, готово :-) делай закладочки на вопросы такие, чтобы не искать ;-) можно в избранное добавить :)

Comment: @Grundy да я что-то не думал что этот вопрос с консолью будет часто всплывать, поэтому не закладывал)

Comment: @Grundy кстати, надо наверное как-то более корректно назвать вопрос дубликат (не знаю как). А то не отображает суть...кмк.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну фактически суть прям как есть - ссылка на объект и неожиданный вывод в консоли. Я тоже не знаю как сформулировать лучше :)

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси Я прочитал ответ на дубликат, понял, что так работает консоль в Хроме. Но то, что вы написали, что ссылка одна и та же - о чём именно это говорит, расскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: В консоль вывелось значение по ссылке. Значение по ссылке обновилось до вывода, и вы увидели одинаковые цифры. Если написать возвращаемую функцию так: `return function innerFunc() { counter++; console.log(counter); return counter;}`, то вы увидите все изменения. Кстати, можно и анонимную стрелочную вернуть.